# Animate label without resetting timeout duration

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, async-await, xamarin.android

I have the following method to animate a label for 20 seconds.

```
    public class BlinkTriggerBehavior : Behavior<Label>
{
    CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    protected override void OnAttachedTo(Label bindable)
    {
        base.OnAttachedTo(bindable);
        bindable.PropertyChanged += Animate; // binding property changed event
    }
    private async void Animate(object obj, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        if (e.PropertyName == "ClassId")
        {
            VisualElement sender = obj as VisualElement;
            var parentAnimation = new Animation();
            var scaleUpAnimation = new Animation(d => sender.Scale = d, 1, 1.2, Easing.SpringIn);
            var fadeOutAnimation = new Animation(d => sender.Opacity = d, 1, 0, Easing.Linear);
            var scaleDownAnimation = new Animation(d => sender.Scale = d, 1.2, 1, Easing.SpringOut);
            var fadeInAnimation = new Animation(d => sender.Opacity = d, 0, 1, Easing.Linear);
            parentAnimation.Add(0, 0.5, fadeOutAnimation);
            parentAnimation.Add(0, 0.5, scaleUpAnimation);
            parentAnimation.Add(0.5, 1, scaleDownAnimation);
            parentAnimation.Add(0.5, 1, fadeInAnimation);
            parentAnimation.Commit(sender, "BlinkingVisualElement", 16, 800, repeat: () => true);
            await Task.Delay(20000);
            parentAnimation.Commit(sender, "BlinkingVisualElement", 16, 800, repeat: () => false);
        }

    }
    protected override void OnDetachingFrom(Label bindable)
    {
        base.OnDetachingFrom(bindable);
        bindable.PropertyChanged -= Animate;
    }
}
```

This method can get called multiple times within 20 seconds. It works fine and animates the label for a full 20 seconds if called one time and wait for 20 seconds before firing the second call. I want it to animate 20 seconds whenever this method is fired.

Now what is happening

I called the method the first time on

9:00:00 AM

It animates till 9:00:20

If I call the method the second time on

9:00:12 AM

It still animates till 9:00:20 only(8 seconds only). I want it to animate till 9:00:32

Basically I want to reset the timer and show full 20 seconds animation whenever this method is called.

Comment: Did you try wrapping the content of this method in Task.Run, with CancellationToken? This is classic case of using this. You call Cancel on CancellationToken on reentry to this method.

Comment: Can you post a code snippet.I tried to put the animation code in Task.Run with cancellation token.But not working

Comment: Does my solution work for you? If yes, can you please accept it (click the ☑️ in the upper left corner of this answer ) so that we can help more people with same problem:).

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT Sorry for the delay. I was trying different ways to get the solution. Your answer is not working for me. I am editing my question to post full code of class.I am using Behavior to make labels animated. Please check the edited question and try to give me a solution.Your support matters..Thanks

Comment: Why my solution is not working for you?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `System.Timers.Timer` to perform the task the after some delay and reset the timer to reset the delay:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    System.Timers.Timer Timer1 { get; set; }

    int count = 0;
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }


    private async void start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //VisualElement sender = obj as VisualElement;
        //var parentAnimation = new Animation();
        //var fadeOutAnimation = new Animation(d => sender.Opacity = d, 1, 0, Easing.Linear);
        //var fadeInAnimation = new Animation(d => sender.Opacity = d, 0, 1, Easing.Linear);
        //parentAnimation.Add(0, 0.5, fadeOutAnimation);
        //parentAnimation.Add(0.5, 1, fadeInAnimation);
        //parentAnimation.Add(0, 0.5, fadeOutAnimation);
        //parentAnimation.Add(0.5, 1, fadeInAnimation);
        //parentAnimation.Add(0, 0.5, fadeOutAnimation);
        //parentAnimation.Add(0.5, 1, fadeInAnimation);
        //parentAnimation.Add(0, 0.5, fadeOutAnimation);
        //parentAnimation.Add(0.5, 1, fadeInAnimation);
        //parentAnimation.Commit(sender, "BlinkingVisualElement", 16, 800, repeat: () => true);

        Console.WriteLine("start");

        if (Timer1 != null)
        {
            Timer1.Stop();
            Timer1.Dispose();
        }

        Timer1 = new System.Timers.Timer();
        //count every 1 second
        Timer1.Interval = 1000;
        Timer1.Enabled = true;

        //reset count
        count = 0;

        Timer1.Start();

        Timer1.Elapsed += (object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e) =>
        {

            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                count++;

                //10 here is the delay time
                if (count == 20)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("finish");
                    
                    //parentAnimation.Commit(sender, "BlinkingVisualElement", 16, 800, repeat: () => false);

                    Timer1.Stop();
                    Timer1.Dispose();
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("current count(seconds):" + count);
                }

            });
        };
    }   
}
```